# How do I get a subset of elements in an array in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I get the 3rd through 6th elements in an array in excel vba? Something like the following.

```
    Dim x(9) as variant, y(3) as variant

    y(0:3) = x(2:5)
```

Comment: could you please attach sample data?

Comment: Not sure how to go about doing that, but shape_names is currently a three dimensional variable with 10 elements in the first dimensions, 4 in the second dimension and 20 in the third. I would like to take a subset of the 20 elements in the third dimension.

Comment: You could add a simplified example as long as it's representative of what you're trying to do.. Colors, Foods, Flavors, could be 3D for example.  Or try Googling your question.

Comment: Do my edits to the question help clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VBA, unlike in python for example, we cannot directly "subset" an array.

We can only loop for the indices of interest by specifying `i` and `j` to be between certain bounds e.g. `i` to be between rows 1 and 2, `j` to be between columns 2 and 3. Of course, we can also directly index into the array by position e.g. `arr(1)`.
`i` just a variable representing the row index, `j` the column index.

Or, we can use `Index` to "slice" out a particular row or column; which I guess you might call subsetting but from your syntax I think you are thinking in the manner of python for example.

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(array,n, 0)` will slice row `n` out of array

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(array, 0, n)` will slice column `n` out of array

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ArrayStuff()
    Dim arr(0 To 5) As Long, i As Long
    For i = 0 To 5
        arr(i) = i
    Next

    'Loop only required indices
    For i = 2 To 3
        Debug.Print arr(i)
    Next

    'Slice via Application.WorksheetFunction.Index
    Dim arr2(0 To 2, 0 To 2) As Long, j As Long, counter As Long

    For i = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1) '<==  here can specify particular rows
        For j = LBound(arr2, 2) To UBound(arr2, 2) '<== here can specify particular columns
            counter = counter + 1
            arr2(i, j) = counter
        Next
    Next

    MsgBox Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr2, 0, 1)), ",") 'slice a column out
    MsgBox Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr2, 1, 0), ",") 'slice a row out
    MsgBox Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr2, 2, 0), ",") 'slice a row out
End Sub
```

Comment: So there's no way of extracting all the elements in a certain dimension? This is a simple task in python or MATLAB but I can't find anything related to this in VBA.

Comment: Yes. See my use of Index (this has a maximum number of elements  though) . Or using a loop specifying that dimension.

Comment: Yes it lovely and easy in python!

Comment: If I have a third dimension is there a way to get the elements in that dimension? This index method looks like it's meant for two dimensions.

Comment: Yup  I believe so though will have a lookl. A loop would be the obvious choice for 3D. I think there are custom functions that may be out there that may do the job. Your worksheet has 2D of row and column so not surprising.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who does not want to use loop or range method to deal this issue,
here is a tested solution to process a subset (need not to be whole row or column) of an array:

```
Application.Sum(Application.Index(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 0, Evaluate("ROW(2:5)")))
```

which sums the 2nd to 5th element of the array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
For an array with two dimensions, simply do the following:

```
Application.Average(.Index(DataArray, Evaluate("ROW(17:21)"), 5))
```

will calculate the average of the five elements subset (row 17 to 21, column 5) of the 2 dimensions array "DataArray".

BTW, I've not yet tried to evaluate the efficiency of this method, but it's truly a workaround. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

### A Python Slice Clone

I recently was wanting the same functionality that you gave in your example, which basically mimics Pythons [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) method — so I decided to write the code to do just that.

Feel free to read my code comments to understand how it works, but it should be identical to pythons `[start:stop:step]` format.

One note, I did write this expecting the base to be set to 0, so if your base is different the code might need to be enhanced first.

```vb
' The Slice function takes an input array and returns a new array
' that contains a subset of the elements from the input array.
'
' The subset is defined by the `startIndex`, `stopIndex`, and `stepCount`
' parameters.
'
' The `startIndex` parameter specifies the index of the first
' element to include in the result. If `startIndex` is negative,
' it counts from the end of the input array.
'
' The `stopIndex` parameter specifies the index of the first element
' to exclude from the result. If `stopIndex` is negative, it counts
' from the end of the input array.
'
' The `stepCount` parameter specifies how many elements to skip
' between each element in the result. For example, if `stepCount`
' is 2, every other element will be included in the result. If
' `stepCount` is negative then it works in reverse order.
'
' @author Robert Todar <robert@roberttodar.com>
Public Function Slice( _
    ByVal arr As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal startIndex As Long = 0, _
    Optional ByVal stopIndex As Long = 0, _
    Optional ByVal stepCount As Long = 1 _
) As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim currentIndex As Long
    Dim resultIndex As Long

    If stepCount = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, "Slice", "Step count must be greater than or less than zero."
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Handle negative indices for startIndex and stopIndex by
    ' converting them to positive indices.
    If startIndex < 0 Then startIndex = UBound(arr) + 1 + startIndex
    If stopIndex < 0 Then stopIndex = UBound(arr) + 1 + stopIndex

    If stepCount > 0 Then
        ' Calculate the stop index if it is not provided (i.e., if it is zero).
        If stopIndex = 0 Then stopIndex = UBound(arr) + 1
        
        ' Calculate the size of the result array based on
        ' start/stop indices and step count.
        resultIndex = (stopIndex - startIndex) \ stepCount - 1
        
        ' Adjust the stopIndex as it is excluded from the results.
        ' This is done after getting the resultIndex as the array
        ' is base 0 and will still need to account for that 0 index.
        stopIndex = stopIndex - 1

    Else
        ' If no input is provided then the start and
        ' stops need to get flipped from the start to
        ' the end.
        If startIndex = 0 Then startIndex = UBound(arr)
        If stopIndex = 0 Then stopIndex = -1

        ' Need to add 1 to the stopindex as it needs to
        ' be excluded from the results. In this senerio,
        ' this is done before the resultIndex is calculated as
        ' we don't have to account for the 0 index.
        stopIndex = stopIndex + 1
        resultIndex = (startIndex - stopIndex) \ Abs(stepCount)
    End If
    
    ' Create a new array with appropriate size to store results.
    ' and get the starting result index. This will be incremented 
    ' each iteration.
    ReDim result(0 To resultIndex)
    resultIndex = LBound(result)

    ' Fill in values for resulting array using start/stop indices
    ' and step count as specified by user inputs.
    For currentIndex = startIndex To stopIndex Step stepCount
        result(resultIndex) = arr(currentIndex)
        resultIndex = resultIndex + 1
    Next currentIndex
    
    ' Return resulting sliced array back to user.
    Slice = result
End Function
```

### Demo

Here is a demo showing the python method compared to my version of it.

```vb
Sub DemoSliceFunction()
    Dim a As Variant
    a = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    Debug.Print "Starting Data", Join(a)
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [::]", Join(Slice(a))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [1:]", Join(Slice(a, 1))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [-1:]", Join(Slice(a, -1))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [-2:]", Join(Slice(a, -2))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [:4]", Join(Slice(a, , 4))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [1:4]", Join(Slice(a, 1, 4))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [:-3]", Join(Slice(a, , -3))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [1:-2]", Join(Slice(a, 1, -2))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [-3:-2]", Join(Slice(a, -3, -2))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [::2]", Join(Slice(a, , , 2))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [::-1]", Join(Slice(a, , , -1))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [-3::-1]", Join(Slice(a, -3, , -1))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [-4::-1]", Join(Slice(a, -4, , -1))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [:-3:-1]", Join(Slice(a, , -3, -1))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [:-4:-1]", Join(Slice(a, , -4, -1))
    Debug.Print "Python Example: [-2:-5:-1]", Join(Slice(a, -2, -5, -1))
End Sub
```

### Testing

In addition, I have provided my test scripts for this method.

```vb
Sub TestSliceFunction()
    Dim a As Variant
    a = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    Debug.Assert Join(a) = "0 1 2 3 4 5"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a)) = "0 1 2 3 4 5"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, 1)) = "1 2 3 4 5"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, -1)) = "5"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, -2)) = "4 5"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, , 4)) = "0 1 2 3"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, 1, 4)) = "1 2 3"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, , -3)) = "0 1 2"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, 1, -2)) = "1 2 3"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, -3, -2)) = "3"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, , , 2)) = "0 2 4"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, , , -1)) = "5 4 3 2 1 0"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, -3, , -1)) = "3 2 1 0"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, -4, , -1)) = "2 1 0"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, , -3, -1)) = "5 4"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, , -4, -1)) = "5 4 3"
    Debug.Assert Join(Slice(a, -2, -5, -1)) = "4 3 2"

    Debug.Print "TestSliceFunction: PASS"
End Sub
```